# Get the dates of the start and end of consecutive values with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
             DATE    CODE      QUARTER  PP
0        1964-01-01  100007    1964Q1  NaN
1        1964-01-02  100007    1964Q1  NaN
2        1964-01-03  100007    1964Q1  NaN
3        1964-01-04  100007    1964Q1  NaN
4        1964-01-05  100007    1964Q1  NaN
            ...     ...       ...  ...
10656619 2023-03-27  118004    2023Q1  0.0
10656620 2023-03-28  118004    2023Q1  0.0
10656621 2023-03-29  118004    2023Q1  0.0
10656622 2023-03-30  118004    2023Q1  0.0
10656623 2023-03-31  118004    2023Q1  0.0

[2647935 rows x 4 columns]
```

I would like to group by CODE and QUARTER, then obtain the maximum value of consecutive days in which PP<1, obtain the start and end date where the maximum value of consecutive days was had in which PP<1, and finally obtain the amount of total nas.

To calculate the maximum value of consecutive days in which PP<1, i did this code:

```
df['CONDITION']=(df['PP']<1)
#CALCULATE THE maximum value of consecutive days in which PP<1
max_values = (df.groupby(['CODE','QUARTER'])
       .apply(lambda g: (g['CONDITION'].ne(g['CONDITION'].shift()).cumsum() # Group continuous 
                         [g['CONDITION']]                                   # Keep True
                         .value_counts().max()))                            # Find max True
       .to_frame('MAX_CONSEC_VALUES').reset_index())
```

But i need also the start and end date where the maximum value of consecutive days was had in which PP<1, and the amount of total nas. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregates for this. As far as I understand you need to [aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) by groups. Or do you want to get from the maximums: the start and end dates and the amount?

```
df1 = df[df['PP'] < 1].groupby(['CODE', 'QUARTER']). \
    agg({'PP': ['max', 'sum'], 'DATE': ['first', 'last']}).reset_index()

df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)
```

If you need to find the sum of the maximums, the start and end dates are the first and last rows, right?

Here, indexes are extracted by groups, where the maximum values are. And a selection of the necessary rows is made: `df.loc[ind]`

```
ind = df[df['PP'] < 1].groupby(['CODE', 'QUARTER'])['PP'].idxmax()

df1 = df.loc[ind].copy().reset_index(drop=True)


aaa = pd.DataFrame({'first': [df1.loc[0, 'DATE']],
                    'last': [df1.loc[len(df1) - 1, 'DATE']],
                    'sum': [df1['PP'].sum()]})
```

Comment: the second one: get from the maximums: the start and end dates and the amount

Comment: completed the answer.